# docker, waiting for SSH to be available

Tags: macos, docker, ssh, docker-machine

I installed docker CE and its ToolBox on "MAC OSX Yosemite 10.10.5", and when I launch the "Docker Quickstart Terminal" I get the message below saying **waiting for SSH to be available** and asking for a **password**. Please suggest a solution, any answer will be highly appreciated.

P.S: Similar questions didn't help, so please don't mark the question as a duplicate

```
Running pre-create checks...
Creating machine...
(default) Copying /Users/macbookpro/.docker/machine/cache/boot2docker.iso to   
/Users/macbookpro/.docker/machine/machines/default/boot2docker.iso...
(default) Creating VirtualBox VM...
(default) Creating SSH key...
(default) Starting the VM...
(default) Check network to re-create if needed...
Error creating machine: Error in driver during machine creation: Unable to start the VM: /usr/local/bin/VBoxManage startvm default --type headless failed:
VBoxManage: error: The virtual machine 'default' has terminated unexpectedly during startup with exit code 1 (0x1)
VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005), component MachineWrap, interface IMachine

Starting "default"...
(default) Check network to re-create if needed...
Unable to start the VM: /usr/local/bin/VBoxManage startvm default --type headless failed:
VBoxManage: error: The virtual machine 'default' has terminated unexpectedly during startup with exit code 1 (0x1)
VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005), component MachineWrap, interface IMachine
Regenerate TLS machine certs?  Warning: this is irreversible. (y/n):    
Regenerating TLS certificates
Waiting for SSH to be available...
Password:
```

Comment: Try removing virtualbox, then remove docker, then install only docker again

Comment: @Robert i tried that before, but it didn't work, do you have another suggestion ?

Answer (score 1):

Go to launch VirtualBox, check for updates (at top left, beside the Apple icon),
Update VirtualBox then I solved this.

ps: I also changed VirtualBox(default) setting [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IrE1C.png)

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue (when installing Docker Toolbox on a Mac that had an old copy of VirtualBox). I can confirm that uninstalling VirtualBox solved the problem for me. (In addition to deleting the VirtualBox app, I also manually cleaned some residual directories, using the process described in https://nektony.com/how-to/uninstall-virtualbox-on-mac). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For me, this happened because I had recently disabled - following [this advice](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/12701/90894) - the annoying "the disk was not ejected properly" notification messages every time I unlocked the mac:

```
sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/com.apple.DiskArbitration.diskarbitrationd.plist DADisableEjectNotification -bool YES && sudo pkill diskarbitrationd
```

But alas, that had broken a bunch of system components including disk mounting (which the Docker .dmg or CLI installation needs). This [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/444019/90894) to revert changes made by the command above came to my rescue:

```
sudo mv /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/com.apple.DiskArbitration.diskarbitrationd.plist /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/com.apple.DiskArbitration.diskarbitrationd.plist-backup
```